# How to tell VLC to use a different set of configuration files?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, config-files

I have a 3 monitor setup. I want to run VLC 3 instances to 3 different monitors.

I setup my preference and copied the `vlcrc` and `vlc-qt-interface.ini` file to a folder say `vlc2` and I tried running a `.bat` file with the following:

```
vlc.exe --config c:\vlc2\vlcrc
```

and even:

```
vlc.exe --config="c:\vlc2\vlcrc"
```

But no matter what I do, it seems to still be getting the settings from the orignal location: `%APPDATA%\vlc\`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From their documentation, it does not appear that VLC supports running alternate config files as a starting argument. Have you found documentation that indicates that it does?

Comment: There's `--config=...`  param  and it works fine. So the question is missing info like how exactly the batch looks or what's inside the configuration file.

Comment: Did you also try with capital `C` drive? Capital letters often matter and should be preserved whenever possible, I doubt it's the case here, but should be as proper as possible when asking questions here.